# Watch directory and sub directory changed

Tags: java

I have make some code for detect changed in directory `C:/my_dir` it work great. ([I follow this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html))

But I need watcher also detect changed in all sub directory too.

like `C:/my_dir/*` Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is recursion.

you need to walk through each subdirectory in your directory... pseudocode:

```
function iteratePath(File root, List<File> registerMe) {
      if (root!= null && root.isDirectory())  {
          registerMe.add(root);
          for (File f : root.listFiles()) {
              iteratePath(f, registerMe);
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the Watch Service API, you have to register a separate watch for each subdirectory.

I'm not sure whether you want to watch only the root directory's children, or the whole tree of directories under the root directory.

If it is the former, you can use `Files.newDirectoryStream()` to iterate through the directory's sub-directories:

```
for (Path subDir : Files.newDirectoryStream(rootPath,
        new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
                return Files.isDirectory(entry);
            }
        }) {
    // add watcher
}
```

If the latter, then you can use the `Files.walkFileTree()` method instead. In fact, this is what they do in the example that you linked to. Have a look at the `registerAll()` method in [WatchDir.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java).

Don't forget that if a new subdirectory appears later, you may also want to add a watcher for that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [FileAlterationMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationMonitor.html) from Apache Commons IO library. The API is fairly easy to use and there are some examples [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-io-2.0/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationMonitorTestCase.java.shtml).